# Referencing methods of a class from within a different class using kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have an application with multiple screens, and I am trying to call a method of my ScreenOne from within another screen. The code is a minimal example.

I would like to know the proper method(s) of referencing this method of ScreenOne when I am within my second screen.

```
cart_list = {}

    class ScreenOne(Screen):
        def update_cart(self):
        cart_list.update({'Item one': 1.00})

        for key, value in cart_list:
            print(key, value)

     class ScreenTwo(Screen):
           pass
```

The associated kv code is as follows

```
ScreenTwo:
    Button:
        id: item_1
        text: "Add to cart"
        on_press: MainScreen.update_cart()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

### kv file

1. Add `id` to ScreenOne.
2. Each screen has by default a property `manager` that gives you the instance of the [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage) used.
3. Reference the method using `root.manager.ids.screen_one.update_cart()`

Below are some minor updates required in the Python script.

### py file

1. Declare `cart_list` as `global` in method, `update_cart`
2. Append `.items()` to `cart_list` e.g. `for key, value in cart_list.items():`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

cart_list = {}


class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def update_cart(self):
        global cart_list
        cart_list.update({'Item one': 1.00})

        for key, value in cart_list.items():
            print(key, value)


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

ScreenManager:
    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one
        name: 'screen1'
    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: 'screen2'

<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Goto Screen Two'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen2'
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'


<ScreenTwo>:
    Button:
        id: item_1
        text: "Add to cart"
        on_press: root.manager.ids.screen_one.update_cart()
```

## Output

[image: Output]